# pm2 error: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, babeljs, pm2

I get this error when I ran command `pm2 start app.js`. I tried to

- install `esm`
- change file extension to `app.mjs`

return another error: `ERR_REQUIRE_ESM`. It was fine before I update nodejs and pm2. No idea why get this error after update.

```
0|app      | import express from 'express';
0|app      | ^^^^^^
0|app      |
0|app      | SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

---

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "module-resolver",
        {
          "alias": {
            "@query": "./query",
            "@lib": "./lib"
          }
        }
      ],
      ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
    ]
 }
```

nodejs: 12.18.0
npm: 6.14.6
pm2: 4.4.0

Comment: were you able to fix this?

Comment: @JeffyMathew i'm not really fixing it but i just build the files with babel and run with build files instead

Comment: thanks. I tried starting pm2 on server once manually, and latter `pm2 deploy` were working.